# Which philosopher said the fear of anticipating an evil is worse than the evil itself?

Tags: reference-request, fear

Which philosopher said the fear of anticipating an evil is worse than the evil itself?

Perhaps Aristotle (in [*Nichomachean Ethics*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Ethics3.htm#14)?) said something along these lines?

Comment: I'm doubly unsure, whether my memory is correct or if my memory would serve you right, here, but I think Aquinas said that Hell might be a state where ghosts are afraid of being burned in Hell, but so he wondered about whether this fear would be enough for the image of Hell, or if it would have to be a realized fear.

Comment: It was Peregrin Took.

Comment: "*Fear is a greater evil than the evil itself. O daughter of little faith, what do you fear? No, fear not; you walk on the sea, amid the winds and the waves, but it is with Jesus*",  [St. Francis de Sales, Letters to Persons in the World, n328](https://www.immaculatalibrary.com/book-snippets/2021-06-05-fear-nothing-when-god-is-with-you.html).

Comment: *"Nothing is so much to be feared as fear.”* -Thoreau, in his journal entry for September 7, 1851. Paraphrased by Roosevelt in his inaugural address.

Comment: @CriglCragl No, that's not it. It's more along the lines of \@Conifold's quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

King David, [Psalm 13:5](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=13&l=5-#x) (= [52:6](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=52&l=6-#x)a):

> They have not called upon the Lord: there have **they trembled for fear, where there was no fear**.

Answer (score 2):

One kind of sentiment that fits the description in the question was characteristic to the Stoics. Because for the Stoics what we usually view as evil, like sickness and death, was deemed to be not evil but indifferent. Whereas good and evil lie only in our judgements. Here is Epictetus:

> It isn’t the things themselves that disturb people, but the
> judgements that they form about them. Death, for instance, is nothing
> terrible, or else it would have seemed so to Socrates too; no, it is
> in the judgement that death is terrible that the terror lies.

(Epictetus, Enchiridion 5)

Comment: Epicurus also is attributed as saying: "Death is nothing to fear, because when I am, death is not and when death is, I am not" (not exact quote)

Comment: @NikosM. Yes I had Epicurus in mind when I started my answer with the words "one kind..". Epicurus is another kind.

Comment: However, judgement seems universally categorical and hard to avoid. For example here for the OP questioner to accept this answer or not needs their judgement...